# Spark Temptable vs Broadcasting

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a question/opinion that needs experts suggestion.

I have a table called ***config*** that contains some configuration information as the table name suggests. I need this details to be accessed from all the executors during my job's life cycle. So my first option is ***Broadcasting*** them in List[Case Class] .But suddenly got an idea of making the ***config*** as Temptable using `registerTempTable()` and use it accross  my job.

This temp table approach  can be used an alternative to Broadcast variables ( I have extensive hands-on on Broadcasting)?

Comment: Do you mean using `registerTempTable()` and then doing a join?

Comment: I will not use any join in my job. i will simply access the config table content for some filtration against my dataset. so no role for joines here ..

Answer (score 1):

`registerTempTable` does just give you the possibilty to run plain sql queries on your dataframe, there is no performance benefit/caching/materialization involved.

You should go with broadcasting (I would suggest to use a `Map` for configuration parameters)

Comment: Thanks for the response and I know the fact that Temp tables are not cached by default. so i take your suggestion of going ahead with broadcasting with List[Case class] since I have another scenario where my keys will be duplicated

Comment: Also Thank you for pointing out the down sides of the approach

Answer (score 0):

registerTempTable() then using it for lookup, will mostly use the broadcast join only internally given the scenario the table/config file  size < 10MB.

Comment: thanks for the response.  why the size limitations and can you pls share it if it's mentioned anywhere on the docs ? it will be helpful to project tis point to my team